# How can I build executables which can be run in Windows XP using Visual Studio 2012 and Intel Compiler XE 2013?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, windows-xp

When I develop a application which can be run in `Window XP` using `Visual Studio 2012`,
I set **`Visual Studio 2012 - Windows XP (v110_xp)`** to the **`platform toolset`** property.

But if I want to build the application using `Intel Compiler XE 2013` with `Visual Studio 2012`,
that property should be **`Intel C++ Compiler XE 13.0`** I suppose.

And a built executable with the property can't be run in `Windows XP` with message "$APPNAME is not a valid Win32 application."

How can I build executables which can be run in `Window XP` using `Visual Studio 2013` and `Intel Compiler XE 2013`?

My development environment is as follows:

- Development machine : `Window 7 Update1`
- Target machine : `Window XP SP3`
- Compiler : `Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Update3` and `Intel C++ Composer XE 2013`

Comment: Have you tried defining the macros given in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

Comment: If you have a copy of the Visual Studio toolkit - try this on the exe - dumpbin /headers /all exename - this may give you some clue - is the binary a x86 binary or not?

Comment: It seems [DependencyWalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) will give you more information of the reason on target WinXP environment.

Comment: DependencyWalker said `OS Ver` and `Subsystem Ver` are `6.0`. after tried the solution, these values became `5.1`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a solution in Intel official articles.

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/linking-applications-using-visual-studio-2012-to-run-on-windows-xp